# Quick Docstrings in Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm starting to play with Colaboratory but I've noticed that `shift-tab` doesn't pop up Docstrings for functions as it does in Jupyter.

Is this functionality absent or just accessed some other way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shift-tab dedents. To see contextual help inline, hit tab after an open parens, e.g.,

```
import os
os.open(
```

Or, execute the cell with a trailing `?` and help will open in the bottom pane, e.g,.

```
import os
os.open?
```

Comment: This is the best solution I also could come up with; despite being far from ideal. But what can you do with Google sometimes?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 25):

This is what helped me e.g.
Image( and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space bar</kbd>
do it with only one bracket.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, quick and shortest way

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> `+` <kbd>Space</kbd> helped me. Both for docstring and autocomplete.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2020-03-20 on Chrome, if you just mouse over the function, a small pop-up shows the input parameters.

As you start typing them auto completion is offered.

And if you press Ctrl while hovering, the function becomes a link that when clicked opens up the documentation of the function.

[image: getting function parameters and documentation within Colab]

Autocomplete works with Ctrl+Space or simply Tab depending on situation.

Note: It must know the type of the object it is working with. So if you do data.transform() and data has no value yet, Colab won't know what to display because .transform() depends on what you apply it to. You can select the line(s) where data is created and run only those with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (run selected lines only).

Comment: Is there any equivalent for the properties? In Jupyter Shift + Tab works also for properties.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Space or start typing the name and press Tab, it will offer you autocomplete.

Answer (score 3):

`space` works for me. If you've closed a pop-up docstring (e.g with the `esc` key), then you can reopen it by pressing `space`.

This will also input a space, so you can remove it with `backspace` but the docstring will remain in view. As usual, which docstring you get will depend on where your caret is.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a parenthesis or between arguments (eg after a comma), tab will show you the docstring -- so if you are typing something like `print('hello', sep='')`, then tab after the paren or between the comma and the next arg will show you the docstring.

Hope that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 getting detailed doc string shortcut is definitely Ctrl+Space

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google colab provide `go to definition` and peek option when you right click on a library. In case you dont get any menu, use the keyboard shortcut insted.
[image: Read documentation in google colab]

Answer (score 0):

If you already wrote the function there might be an easier way than Ctrl + Space. Point your mouse at the function and then hold Ctrl. That worked for me well.