# Docstrings in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

**What can be the reason behind the absence of Docstrings while writing any function in google colaboratory.**
We all know how useful Docstring is while coding and this is the reason I need it many times a day
I tried using the following things:

1. shift-tab
2. keeping mouse within parenthesis
3. using space and then backspace within the parenthesis.
   4.ctrl-shift-space

*[This is a sample just to show that the mouse is in between parenthesis and there is no Docstring. I have tried for many more functions]*

also viewed ([Quick Docstrings in Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042988/quick-docstrings-in-colaboratory)),
but none of the methods mentioned worked in my case. Is there any other possibilities or change in some setting required?

Answer (score 0):

Hit tab after opening a bracket

List.apppend(

Then hit a tab
or
you can type List.append?

Even try ctrl + space( I personally  used it)

Comment: ctrl+space gives:  all, and, any, ArithmaticError and such operators suggestions rather than Docsting

Comment: You can try the first 2 methods.